# jQuery animate, ignore additional clicks until animation is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created some script to show a list when a bolded title is clicked on, and hide that same list when another title is clicked on.

Is there a way for animate to ignore additional clicks while the animation is running?

Here is a fiddle that I created:

http://jsfiddle.net/VBh5f/

Here is the HTML:

```
<ul id="accordion" class="collapsible">
  <li class="main"><span>+</span> <b>Oil and Vinegar</b>
        <ul>
            <li>Extra Virgin Olive Oil</li>
            <li>Nut and Seed Oils</li>    
            <li>Balsamic Vinegar</li>
            <li>Wine Vinegar</li>
        </ul>
  </li>         
  <li class="main"><span>+</span> <b>Coffee and Tea</b>
        <ul>
            <li>Mariage Frères Tea</li>    
            <li>Peaberry&#039;s Coffee and Tea</li>
        </ul>
  </li>    
</ul>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function show(i) {
  $('.main > ul:eq('+i+')').css(
    {
      display:'block'
    }
    ).animate(
    {
      opacity: 1
    },
    100,
    function() {
      $(this).parent().find('span').text('-');   
    }
  );
}

function hide(i) {
  $('.main > ul:eq('+i+')').css(
    {
      display:'none'
    }
    ).animate(
    {
      opacity: 1
    },
    100,
    function() {
      $(this).parent().find('span').text('+');   
    }
  );
}

function listControl(i, doWhat) {
  $('.main').each(function(index, elem) {
    hide(index); 
  });
  if (doWhat === 'showList') {
    show(i);
  }
}

function click() {
  $('.main').on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).find('ul').css('display') === 'none' ) {
      listControl( $(this).index(), 'showList' );
    }
    else {
      listControl( $(this).index() );
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  click(); 
});
```

Here is the CSS:

```
ul {list-style:none;}
.main > ul {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VBh5f/10/

```
$('.main').on('click', function() {
        if($('#accordion ul').is(':animated')) return;
        if ( $(this).find('ul').css('display') === 'none' ) {
            listControl( $(this).index(), 'showList' );
        }
        else {
            listControl( $(this).index() );
        }
    });
```

Comment: +1 This shows the nubbin of the required answer: [`.is(':animated')`](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)

Comment: Ya, but i had hard time to see any animation in the OP jsfiddle

Comment: Thank you.  If you don't mind, what is the .is(':animated') doing?  And return in this case means void right?  Sorry, I am just experimenting to learn, I had not seen .is() before.

Edit:  I checked it out on jQuery's site.  Thanks also Orblin for the link.

Comment: .is() jquery method return a boolean. So .is(':animated') return true if selector is currently animated and so return nothing. Then, extra code in function is ignored.

Comment: Aye, as @roasted says - that initial `if` is checking if the element is animated, and if it is aborting the event handler by returning, ie. "if currently animating, do nothing".

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a var :

```
isMoving = true;
if(!isMoving){
//your code
}
```

And after in the callback `isMoving = false;`